# Parse array of subdocuments in JSON PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I got the following JSON string in PHP:

```
{  
   "status":"200",
   "message":"Saved picklist found",
   "data":{  
      "_id":{  
         "$oid":"5aab871dbcdcab3ab0005cd3"
      },
      "username":"admin",
      "list_count":"3",
      "list":[  
         {  
            "id":"1",
            "data":"AUTOGENERATED1",
            "x":"33",
            "y":"33"
         },
         {  
            "id":"2",
            "data":"AUTOGENERATED2",
            "x":"22",
            "y":"22"
         },
         {  
            "id":"3",
            "data":"AUTO",
            "x":"33",
            "y":"33"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

that I decode to an array using the following:

```
json_decode($response, true);
```

I would like to loop through the array and extract for example username and list_count. I tried the following code for that:

```
foreach ($response['data'] as $resp) {
     echo $resp['list_count'];
}
```

which does not work. Any suggestions on how to extract username and list_count?

I would also like to loop through the `list` array and get the values for each object within that array, any suggestions on how that can be done?

Comment: Please check my answer. It will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
$dd = json_decode($json,true);
echo $dd["data"]["username"]."<br/>"; //get value of username

//Loop through list to get all values
foreach($dd["data"]["list"] as $key=>$value){
echo $value['id']."<br/>";
echo $value['data']."<br/>";
echo $value['x']."<br/>";
echo $value['y']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: He needs only username and listcount. i.e Not other attributes.

Comment: I would also like to loop through the list array and get the values for each object within that array, any suggestions on how that can be done? - Last line in question, can you please tell me the meaning of this? @DarshanJain

Comment: Check the question: He mentioned that extract **username and list_count**

Comment: Can't you see the last two lines in question ? @DarshanJain

Comment: Which two lines are you talking about?

Comment: ** I would also like to loop through the list array and get the values for each object within that array, any suggestions on how that can be done? ** THIS. @DarshanJain

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in order to get the username and listcount from the JSON.

```
$arr       = json_decode($response,true);
$userName  = $arr['data']['username'];
$listCount = $arr['data']['list_count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$values    = json_decode($response,true);
$username  = $arr['data']['username'];
$listCount = $arr['data']['list_count'];
if ($listCount > 0) {
    foreach ($values['data']['list'] as $list) {
        //Here you are looping inside lists and have the following
        // $list['id']
        // $list['data']
        // $list['x']
        // $list['y']
    }
}
```